# gdal /vsis3/ on NetCDF from Earthdata

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, netcdf, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to access data from NASA's Earthdata S3 buckets, but I get a `"<filename> does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name."` error after waiting a long time (± 50 minutes, the process is downloading some data the whole time) doing the following:

```
from osgeo import gdal

gdal_config_options = {
    "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": creds["accessKeyId"],
    "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN":  creds["sessionToken"],
    "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": creds["secretAccessKey"],
}

url = "/vsis3/prod-lads/VNP02IMG/VNP02IMG.A2023193.1942.002.2023194025636.nc"
    
for k, v in gdal_config_options.items():
    gdal.SetConfigOption(k, v)

out = gdal.Info(url)
```

The `creds` variable is a dictionary with temporary credential information that I get from [here](https://data.laadsdaac.earthdatacloud.nasa.gov/s3credentials), you need a free account to get them.

When I introduce an error in one of the keys/tokens (e.g. `"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": creds["accessKeyId"] + "x"`, I do get a message immediately saying my credentials are unknown. So I do think they are being ingested correctly by GDAL.

I also managed to download the entire file using `boto3`, by doing the following:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=creds["accessKeyId"],
    aws_secret_access_key=creds["secretAccessKey"],
    aws_session_token=creds["sessionToken"]
)

client.download_file('prod-lads', 'VNP02IMG/VNP02IMG.A2023193.1942.002.2023194025636.nc', 'test.nc')
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how to make this work? In the end I'm interested in accessing the files metadata without downloading the entire file.

Comment: Could you give an example of what the `s3_url` looks like? It should look similar to this `/vsis3/eodata/Sentinel-2/.../file_name.extention` (if using `AWS_VIRTUAL_HOSTING=FALSE`) where `/vsis3/ represents the endpoint, eodata is the bucket and the rest is the item.

Comment: Hi, @PyMapr! The URL I pass to `gdal.Info` is for example `/vsis3/prod-lads/VNP02IMG/VNP02IMG.A2023193.1942.002.2023194025636.nc`, so the bucket-name is `prod-lads`. I just tried setting `AWS_VIRTUAL_HOSTING=FALSE`, but that doens't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer through the gdal-dev mailing list from @Even.

It turns out that when I called `gdal.Info`, GDAL was starting to establish a list of all the files in the directory of the file passed. There are quite a lot of files there, so this slows down the process significantly.

Setting `GDAL_DISABLE_READDIR_ON_OPEN=EMPTY_DIR` in addition to the other configuration options prevents this and `gdal.info` returns the metadata in a couple of seconds.